# is there a way to show boostrap glyphicon on Notes form or view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Users who uses just Notes Client needs to set a glyphicon (in some profile document) that will appear on xPage. So is there a way to show a list of all bootstrap icons in Notes Client? I don't want to add anything in Resources/Images.

Comment: I think frameset combining Notes form and web page with icons preview  would help them.

Comment: What version of Notes they use? With R8.5 and up you can use composite application with Notes form and web preview (in addition to frameset solution, which works with older Notes clients, btw).

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know there is no way of displaying a list of Bootstrap glyph icons (or Font Awesome icons) for easy selection in the Notes client without using XPages.

What I would suggest is to use a text field where the user enters the icon name. Next to the field you can add a help button/action hotspot that opens a URL where the icons are listed, e.g. http://fontawesome.io/icons/
That way the user can find the icon name. Or you can use a combobox and list all icon names in it for the user to select.

I use the latter method for my Domino-based personal homepage/CMS system.

Answer (score 0):

Paste a screenshot of the glypicon web page into a notes page.
Or add the screenshot as image ressource and show is at background of a second column in your profile document table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found and had to copy all glyphicons as PNG into Resources->Images. Then I use special view that shows that resource icons documents in notesUIWorkspace.PickListCollection